# Alguien sabe como relsover los errores Uncaught TypeError de JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un modal que contiene varios botones que hacen la función de estacionamiento con 20 cajones, el cual los llamo desde select que tengo en un formulario.
Tengo un función creado en JavaScript, que al momento de dar clic a un botón cambien de color a rojo y si le doy otro clic cambie a verde, por el momento tengo 5 botones declarados para hacer pruebas, hasta el momento todo funciona bien, pero me percate que me sale un error al abrir la herramienta de inspeccionar.

Función en javascript

```
(function () {
   var btncajon1 = document.getElementById("cajon1");
   btncajon1.addEventListener("click", c1);

   var btncajon2 = document.getElementById("cajon2");
   btncajon2.addEventListener("click", c2);

   var btncajon3 = document.getElementById("cajon3");
   btncajon3.addEventListener("click", c3);

   var btncajon4 = document.getElementById("cajon4");
   btncajon4.addEventListener("click", c4);

   var btncajon5 = document.getElementById("cajon5");
   btncajon5.addEventListener("click", c5);

 var contador = 0;

function c1() {

  if (contador % 2 == 0) {

  btncajon1.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";

} else {
  btncajon1.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
}
contador += 1;
```

}

```
function c2() {

 if (contador % 2 == 0) {

  btncajon2.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
} else {
  btncajon2.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
}
contador += 1;
```

}

```
function c3() {

 if (contador % 2 == 0) {
  btncajon3.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";

} else {
  btncajon3.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
}
contador += 1;
```

}

```
function c4() {

 if (contador % 2 == 0) {

  btncajon4.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";

} else {
  btncajon4.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
}
contador += 1;
```

}

```
function c5() {

 if (contador % 2 == 0) {
  btncajon5.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";

} else {
  btncajon5.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
}

contador += 1;
```

}
})();

Error que sale al inspeccionar

[image: Error]

Comment: Parece ser que el JavaScript era cargando antes de la renderizacion del html

Comment: Gracias, ya lo resolví había colocado mal los script donde no debían de ir.